# What is the reliable way to get all entries of the Elasticsearch index (in Java with Rest client)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

As far as I understand the server and its Java Highlevel Rest client make me use paging when retrieving long sets:

```
        _query = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();              
        SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest(_index);
        SearchSourceBuilder ssb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        ssb.from(_from);
        ssb.size(_count);
        ssb.query(_query);
        sr.source(ssb);                
        SearchResponse response;
            try {
                response = Factory.DB.search(sr);
```

So if I omit `size`, it will fall back to a default 10 or something.

This seems to me a bit unreliable because when I try to query the next "from-to" page, a lot of entries may be removed or added.

Is there a way to get all results at once no matter how big the resultset is?

(implying the server will use some streamish manner to serve the long resultset without being out of memory)

Comment: Have you looked at the scroll api and how to use it from java client https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html

Comment: Nooo, will take a look! Seems what I'm searching for. Thank you!

Comment: @sramalingam24 though looks like it is not a rest client, but will check further

Comment: There should be a corresponding rest client call

Comment: if you are using Java Highlevel Rest client, I think this is what you are looking for: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-high-search-scroll.html

Comment: @sramalingam24 can you please copy your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?